# How to make javascript hold until a function returns a value and then proceed to the next line?

Tags: javascript

I am calculating the driving distance between two points and then alert them.

however calculating the distance method takes like 2 seconds to proceed.

so when i click on the button that alerts the value of the distance the value is null.

if i clicked again it shows the value of the distance.

I am trying to make the code hold until a value is returned from the calculating function:

here is part of my code:

```
 function calculate(cb){
if(!checkSelected()){return false;}


    MQA.withModule('directions', function() {

    /*Uses the MQA.TileMap.addRoute function (added to the TileMap with the directions module)
    passing in an array of location objects as the only parameter.*/
    map.addRoute([
      {street: addr_s[1]  , city: addr_s[2] , state:addr_s[3] , postalCode: addr_s[4]},
      {street: addr_d[1], state: addr_d[2] , state:addr_d[3] , postalCode: addr_d[4]}
    ]);

  });

    MQA.withModule('directions', function() {

      /*Executes the route call with 4 parameters.*/
      MQA.Directions.route(

        /*An array of location objects as the first parameter.*/
        [{ street: addr_s[1]  , city: addr_s[2] , state:addr_s[3] , postalCode: addr_s[4]},
        { street: addr_d[1], state: addr_d[2] , state:addr_d[3] , postalCode: addr_d[4] }],

        /*An object for route options are the second parameter.
        In this case, we are not using any options so we pass in null.*/
       {routeOptions:{routeType:'SHORTEST', avoids:['ferry']}},

        /*You can pass in an instance of MQA.TileMap for the third parameter. If not null, the call will create
        a route ribbon on the map. Again, we are not using a map in this example so we pass in null.*/

 null,
        /*The fourth parameter is the callback function to be executed after the route call. The callback
        will pass the raw response from the route request as a parameter.*/
        cb
      );
  });


   }

   function work(){
  calculate(function (data){

  if(data.route) {

    var distance = data.route.distance;
     var time = data.route.time;
     time_minutes = time/60 ;
     document.forms["myform"]["distance"].value =distance;
      document.forms["myform"]["time"].value =time_minutes ;

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: That comment, _“/*The fourth parameter is the callback function to be executed after the route call.”_ basically already tells you what you need to know. And if _callback function_ doesn’t mean anything to you, go research it.

Comment: the call back function is passed as a parameter in the method and then called using the other method work i thought this may solve the issue however it didnt

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the alert into the callback ...

```
/*The fourth parameter is the callback function to be executed after the route call. The callback
will pass the raw response from the route request as a parameter.*/
cb
```

The callback is fired when all process is complete inside the function the callback is attached to.

Comment: that what i am doing i am setting the values of the form in the cb function still no hope.

Comment: Setting all the values AND fire the alert?

Comment: by just calling the work funciton the form values should be set. for example if i post the valuesof the form to another php page they will be sent as null